# Making a simple input verifier

Tags: python-3.x

what I want is to validate user input in python 3.9 under these conditions:
1-No numbers bigger than 100 allowed.
2-No strings allowed.
3-No floats allowed.
The code seems to work well only with string detection.
Thanks in advance.

```
import random

name = input("Type in your name, sir.\n")
print("Hi", name, "!")
print(
    "\n\n\n##This is a guessing game, where you guess a number that is between zero and the top number that you choose.##")
print("\n\nEnter a top number, and don't exaggerate babe.")
n = input()
verifier = 5
while True:
    try:
        verifier = int(n)
    except ValueError or int(n) > 100:
        print("Nope, neither floats nor strings are allowed buddy...Also don't pick a big'ol num like a 100.")
        n = input()
        continue
```

Comment: That's not how `try..except` works. A `try..except` block only catches errors. You should redo a tutorial. Use an `if` block to check if `verifier > 100` if the conversion to integer succeeds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your max check isn't working since `int(n) > 100` only runs if it wasn't able to convert the string into an integer.

Move the condition after `verifier = int(n)` and it should work.

Your code should look something like this:

```
while True:
    try:
        verifier = int(n)
        if int(n) > 100:
            raise ValueError() # Brings us to the except statement
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Nope, neither floats nor strings are allowed buddy...Also don't pick a big'ol num like a 100.")
        n = input()
        continue
```

By the way, you can probably just remove the `verifier = int(n)` line, assuming you don't use it for anything else.